Plotting a Surface with Multiple Matrices and Custom Colormap Incorporation in Python
I'm trying to plot a surface using Python, and I have four matrices representing the data: img, X, Y, and Z. Here's some contextual information to better understand the problem: X and Y are dimensions in nanometers (nm), img represents the height (typical in microscopy), and Z represents measurements in different regions.
Currently, I've successfully plotted the surface using the following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, img, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()

Now, I want to incorporate the Z matrix into the colormap (cmap) parameter. How can I achieve this? Considering that Z has dimensions Z.shape = (7, 7) while img, X, and Y have dimensions img.shape = X.shape = Y.shape = (46, 47).
I tried adjusting the dimensions of the Z matrix to match the dimensions of the X and Y matrices before plotting the contour plot using the contourf method from matplotlib. However, even after adjusting the dimensions, the error persisted, indicating that the dimensions of X and Z still didn't match. I was expecting that correcting the dimensions would solve the issue and allow for the correct plotting of the contour plot, but that didn't happen.

Do you know what the x/y coordinates are for each element in Z? That information could be used to interpolate Z onto the 46x47 grid.
